# Gradle Failed to resolve google library in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0
>   Failed
>   to resolve: com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0

how to fix above error?

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'

compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

Comment: Try disable offline mode and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are missing Maven Central you can add `repositories` to your gradle file.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
}
```